# how to add html special character in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I want to add degree html code **°**

```
      const degreeNum = d3
        .select(`#windBox${order}`)
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", 250)
        .attr("y", 130)
        .style("font", "bold 50px sans-serif")
        .style("fill", "url(#lgTextDegree)")
        .text(`${degree}`); // here i want to add html code
```

i try Template literals like this

```
.text(`${&#xb0;}`)
```

but not working. How to solve this problem??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [d3.select is not working with special Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41296586/d3-select-is-not-working-with-special-characters)

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31669536/how-to-put-a-degree-symbol-in-an-html-input-field-through-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `.text(String.fromCharCode(176))`

```js
d3.select("#my\\~div_chart").on("click", function(){
    d3.select(this).text(String.fromCharCode(176))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="my~div_chart">Click Me</div>
```

Note the use of escape characters (`\\`) to escape the `~` symbol